# Using git in subtitles creation

Tags: git

I use Aegisub to create subtitled TV series. 
I have a python script that scans all subtitle files in directory and generates TV series with hardsub using `ffmpeg`.

I'm trying to use `git` for *.ass subtitle files. 
I have couple of question:

1. what is the best way to tell an external program that I have finished making subtitles and it is OK to run script to generate hardsubbed series?
2. How to track that I've all hardsubbed files present and that they are up to date?
3. Maybe I should use git for it?
4. is there a way to insert some data like date or subtitle version into *.ass file before commit or release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Why not use post commit hooks to run it automatically, Use python `gitlib` and check that you have committed them all, run your script to generate the hardstubbed files and
2. check the filesize and timestamp of the results
3. Not sure what you mean?
4. Generate the .ass files from python and an input file if you can not simply include a fil e that contains the information.

Comment: > Not sure what you mean? - I mean whether to use git itself or use external scripts. But have already answered question. Thank you.